# Integrate Unity ADS - Unity, Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Работаю над проектом, не могу включить Unity ADS, просто отсутствует кнопка enable, с чем это связано? Возможно ли из-за того что я нахожусь в своей учетной записи, а не в записи где был создан проект? Можно ли просто по старинке скачать SDK Unity ADS и оттуда уже им пользоваться? без активирования Unity Services ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На счёт проблемы скорей всего из за аккаунта вы не можете активировать Unity Services, А вот скачать можно с ассет стора, вот вам [сылка](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/66123).

Установить предполагаю сможете.